# Change docker installation drive

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, jakarta-ee, payara

I would like to install docker (from docker.com) at another drive, since I am using windows and my C drive is almost full.

I have looked at lot's of different ways to do this and they either gave an error or unclear instructions that I did not understand. Most sources I found were from five years ago.

Also, how do I link intellij to it when it is on a different drive?

Thanks